# for nlp, Is there any text corpora with pronunciation alphabet?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

I'm student who started to study nlp with python and nltk.

Since I'm trying to find heteronyms in the text, it looks essential to look for pronunciation aspect of text.

Therefore, I am looking for the text corpus which is provided with correct phonetic alphabet of sentences and words.

https://linguistics.stanford.edu/resources/resources-corpora

I thought some of above link's corpora might be help, but it lseems only standford student can get access to those corpora.

In conclusion, I want to ask where can I find some text sources with, or tagged by correct phonetic alphabet.

I'm not sure I asked politely in the right format because my English is not good and this is my first question on the stack oveflow. Sorry for it :(

Thanks!